# Ant: How to check (programatically) if schemavalidate was successful or not

Tags: ant, xsd-validation, ant-contrib

I would like to know if is possible to check/capture the result of a "schemavalidate"/"xmlvalidate" operation?

The idea is to parse the files in a folder, try to validate each of them against an XSD and get the status of the operation in a property (eventually, output the status and the result of the operation in a log file).

The status of the validation can be then checked in order to know if some other tasks should be performed or not on that particular XML file.

For example:

```
<target name="convert-user-folder">
    <echo>${user.folder}</echo>

    <!-- Iterate all XML files in the folder -->
    <foreach target="validate-xml-file" param="user.input.xml">
      <path>
        <fileset dir="${user.folder}">
          <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>
      </path>
    </foreach>
</target>       

<target name="validate-xml-file">
   <echo message="Validating ${user.input.xml}"/>

   <!-- Checking if XML is well formed -->
   <echo message="Checking if ${user.input.xml} is well formed"/>
   <xmlvalidate file="${user.input.xml}" failonerror="false" lenient="true"/>

   <!-- HOW WE COULD CHECK THE RESULT OF THE VALIDATION OPERATIONS 
        WITHOUT EXITING ?-->

   <!-- Checking if file validates against XSD -->
   <echo message="Checking if ${user.input.xml} validates against schema"/>
   <schemavalidate noNamespaceFile="${xsds.dir}/userInput.xsd" 
        file="${user.input.xml}" failonerror="false"/>

   <!-- HOW WE COULD CHECK THE RESULT OF THE VALIDATION OPERATIONS 
        WITHOUT EXITING? -->

   <!-- HERE WE SHOULD GET IN A PROPERTY THE STATUS OF THE OPERATION AND WRITE 
        IN A FILE SOMETHING LIKE : "OPERATION STATUS: SUCCESS/FAILURE: The reason 
        was: something from the schemavalidate output" -->

    <!-- IF THE OPERATION WAS SUCCESSFUL WE SHOULD CALL SOME TASKS OTHERWISE 
         CALL OTHER TASKS -->
 </target>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed actually was the trycatch from [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html). This solved my problem as in the snippet below.

```
<target name="validate-xml-file">
<echo message="Validating ${user.input.xml}"/>

<!-- Checking if XML is well formed -->
<echo message="Checking if ${user.input.xml} is well formed"/>
<trycatch property="xml.well.formed.result">
  <try>
      <xmlvalidate file="${user.input.xml}" failonerror="true" lenient="true"/>
  </try>
  <catch/>
  <finally/>
</trycatch>

<!-- Checking if file validates against XSD -->
<echo message="Checking if ${user.input.xml} validates against schema"/>
<trycatch property="schema.validation.result">
  <try>
     <schemavalidate noNamespaceFile="${xsds.dir}/userInput.xsd"              
          file="${user.input.xml}" failonerror="true"/>
  </try>
  <catch/>
  <finally/>
</trycatch>

<!-- Create two properties for the results of the validation -->
<condition property="xml.well.formed.result.set" else="false">
      <isset property="xml.well.formed.result"/>
</condition>
<condition property="schema.validation.result.set" else="false">
      <isset property="schema.validation.result"/>
</condition>
    <!-- Here we can write into a HTML format the result of the operation according 
         to the xml.well.formed.result, schema.validation.result a.s.o.) -->

<!-- Also, perform something according to the validation or not of the XML -->
<if>
    <or>
        <equals arg1="${xml.well.formed.result.set}" arg2="true"/>
        <equals arg1="${schema.validation.result.set}" arg2="true"/>
    </or>
    <then>
        <!-- Here we call some task -->
    </then>
    <else>
        <!-- Here we call some other task or just fail to fw the failure -->
    </else>
</if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simplify the solution by using filesets (instead of using the 3rd party [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) "foreach" task).

```
<xmlvalidate failonerror="false" ..>
   <fileset dir="${user.folder}" includes="*.xml"/>
</xmlvalidate>

<schemavalidate failonerror="false" ..>
   <fileset dir="${user.folder}" includes="*.xml"/>
</schemavalidate>
```

I just tested a similar solution and got the following message telling me the file and line throwing the validation issues:

```
[schemavalidate] /path/to/file/file.xml:119:18: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'helloworld'. One of '???' is expected.
```

Comment: Actually, this is not what I want (see also the comments with capital letters in "validate-xml-file"). The validation of each file is part of a much complex process in which I need to process one file at a time. Also, I need to know if the validation for a certain file was successful or not (not just having a message in the console - see my problem description above) i.e. a failure of a file should not stop all the process but instead log from another target, in a custom way, the reason for failure and save the status also in a property. Hope is much clear now :-).

Comment: @Lycaon in that case your issue might have something to do with the foreach task (which is not part of standard ANT). Personally I'd solve this problem differently, use a scripting language like groovy to iterate over each file. Sorry couldn't help further.